# Streamlining Neo4j query that conditionnaly creates new relationships

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database with 3 type of nodes and two relationships:
 `(p:PERSON)-[:manages]->(c:COMPANY)-[:seeks]->(s:SKILLS)`

I want to create a new relationship between the nodes labeled `(:PERSON)` such as:
 `(p1:PERSON)-[:competes_with]->(p2:PERSON)` and 
`(p2:PERSON)-[:competes_with]->(p1:PERSON)` subject to  `p1.name <> p2.name`.
so that I can represent competition for scarce labor in a variety of markets represented by `(s:SKILLS)`.

The condition to establish the new relationship `[:competes_with]` is that 2 distinct persons nodes `(:PERSON)` manage companies that seek at least 3  `(:SKILLS)` profiles that coincide between the 2 companies.

Orders of magnitude are:
|(:PERSON)| = 6000
|(:COMPANY)| = 15000
|(:SKILLS)| = 95000

In my plodding way, what I did was:

```
MATCH (p1:PERSON)-[:manages]->(:COMPANY)-[:seeks]->(s:SKILLS)
WITH p1, collect(DISTINCT s.skill_names) AS p1_skills
MATCH (p2:PERSON)-[:manages]->(:COMPANY)-[:seeks]->(s:SKILLS)
WITH p1,p1_skills, p2, collect(DISTINCT s.skill_names) AS p2_skills
WHERE p1 <> p2
UNWIND p1_skills AS sought_skills
WITH p1,p2, sought_skills, reduce(com_skills=[], sought_skills IN p2_skills | com_skills + sought_skills) AS NCS
WHERE size(NCS) >= 3
MERGE(p1)-[competes_with]->(p2)
MERGE(p2)-[competes_with]->(p1)
```

Given the size of the problem, this causes a 14GB RAM box to crash after a while with an "out-of-memory" exception.
So, besides the fact that I don't know whether my query actually does what I want (it crashes before completing), the question is:
 *Can I streamline this to make it work with smaller memory requirements ? What would the improved query be like ?* Tx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The standard neo4j naming convention is to have camel-case label names, and all-upper-case relationship names (and properties should start with a lower-case character). In this answer, I will follow the standard and use names like `Person` and `MANAGES`.
2. You don't need 2 `COMPETES_WITH` relationships between the same 2 `Person` nodes if the relationship is inherently bidirectional. Neo4j can navigate incoming and outgoing relationships equally easily, and the `MATCH` clause allows a relationship pattern to not specify a direction (e.g., `MATCH (a)-[:FOO]-(b)`). Also, the `MERGE` clause (but not `CREATE`) allows you to specify an undirected relationship -- which ensures that only one relationship exists between the 2 endpoints.
3. It seems that the `COMPETES_WITH` relationship really belongs between `Company` nodes, since that is really the source of the competition. Also, if a `Person` left a company, you should not have to remove any `COMPETES_WITH` relationships from that node (and you should also not have to add a `COMPETES_WITH` relationship to the replacement `Person`).
4. In addition, you should consider whether the `COMPETES_WITH` relationship is really needed in the first place. Every time the skills sought by a `Company` changes, you'd have to recalculate its `COMPETES_WITH` relationships. You should determine whether doing that is worth it, or whether your queries should just dynamically determine a company's competitors as needed.
5. Here is a simplified version of your original query:

   ```
   MATCH (p1:Person)-[:MANAGES]->(:Company)-[:SEEKS]->(s:Skills)<-[:SEEKS]-(:Company)<-[:MANAGES]-(p2:Person)
   WITH p1, p2, COUNT(s) AS num_skills
   WHERE num_skills >= 3
   MERGE(p1)-[:COMPETES_WITH]-(p2);
   ```

   To find the `Person` nodes that compete with a given `Person`:

   ```
   MATCH (p1:Person {id: 123})-[:COMPETES_WITH]-(p2:Person)
   RETURN p1, COLLECT(p2) AS competing_people;
   ```
6. If you changed the data model to have the `COMPETES_WITH` relationship between `Company` nodes:

   ```
   MATCH (c1:Company)-[:SEEKS]->(s:Skills)<-[:SEEKS]-(c2:Company)
   WITH c1, c2, COUNT(s) AS num_skills
   WHERE num_skills >= 3
   MERGE(c1)-[:COMPETES_WITH]-(c2);
   ```

   With this model, to find the `Person` nodes that compete with a given `Person`:

   ```
   MATCH (p1:Person {id: 123})-[:MANAGES]->(:Company)-[:COMPETES_WITH]-(:Company)<-[:MANAGES]-(p2:Person)
   RETURN p1, COLLECT(p2) AS competing_people;
   ```
7. If you did not have `COMPETES_WITH` relationships at all, to find the `Person` nodes that compete with a given `Person`:

   ```
   MATCH (p1:Person {id: 123})-[:MANAGES]->(:Company)-[:SEEKS]->(s:Skills)<-[:SEEKS]-(:Company)<-[:MANAGES]-(p2:Person)
   WITH p1, p2, COUNT(s) AS num_skills
   WHERE num_skills >= 3
   RETURN p1, COLLECT(p2) AS competing_people;
   ```

Comment: Far and away the superior answer. I'm deleting my post; this one includes all info mine had while also being far more efficient, and it has info on best practices.